# 301 Redirect Default Route in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes, http-redirect

I am trying to set up a 301 redirect for the "Default-route" in codeigniter.

I know I can set up a route to another page, but I need it to redirect instead.

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set a controller function on error page where we will call a view

$route['404_override'] = 'errors/index_404';

errors is controller and index_404 is action(function) where we calling our custom view page